# Self-hosted webinar software (or provider located in the EU)

Tags: web-apps, security, educational, privacy

We're currently searching for a self hosted webinar software because we have customers that put a big focus on security and privacy, also we're located in Germany we have to fulfill German and European laws regarding privacy and security.

This is why we decided that US-hosted-only software is out of the picture, ideally we would want a solution to self host (open source or proprietary doesn't matter), costs also not that much of a concern but ideally we would want to buy a license one time without monthly or yearly costs.

We need the following functions:

- moderated (moderators can create seminars and invite participants and also set default permissions and grant and revoke individual permissions, e. g. talking)
- only web-browser needed (at least on the participant side)
- no third-party applications required on participant side (Flash, Silverlight or worse own software etc.)
- support for SSL encryption mandatory
- inviting users via e-mail and/or generated link for the webinar with personal passwords
- statistics (participants lists etc., crucial for us because we need to verify that users participated)
- screen/window-capturing (for slideshows etc.)
- video capturing and streaming
- recording function
- min 100 max users, better 1000
- optional: bidirectional voice communication (best: raised hand model, moderator can grant participants the permission to speak)
- optional: whiteboard ability

I hope I'm not using the wrong platform to ask this question. I searched the internet by myself but I'm basically looking for webinar users who would like to share their experiences.
Most services provide provider-hosted solutions only with fees per month/year or depending on group size. If there is no other solution this would do as well but only for providers located within the EU (bound by European law).

What are your experiences? Do you have any adivse?